# How do Auto-Implemented properties work in C# interfaces?

Tags: c#

If I declare Auto-Implemented properties in C# classes, then `public string Property { get; set; }` becomes:

```
private string _property;

public string get_Property() {
    return _property;
}

public void set_Property(string value) {
    _property = value;
}
```

which includes a private field `string _property`.

If I create an interface, I am allowed to use Auto-Implemented properties like so:

`string Property { get; set; }`

Why can I declare Auto-Implemented properties inside Interface, but I can't use the longer, more verbose syntax that declares private fields? I am aware of the definition that says:

> An interface contains only the signatures of methods, properties, events or indexers

Is the private field in interfaces not generated the same as in classes? Is it generated at all?

Comment: they aren't implemented in the interface. the interface only defines the contract.

Comment: The `get;set;` syntax in an interface just says "the object that implements this interface must have a property that you can set and get".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(As a preface, *yes*, this answer is aware of C# 8.0 *DIM* (default interface methods) and I've included notes to clarify some of the ambiguities introduced by the related changes in C# 8.0 regarding permitted modifiers in interface members)

---

> Why can I declare Auto-Implemented properties inside Interface

They aren't auto-implemented, it's just that the syntax of a property **declaration** in an `interface` is identical to the syntax for an auto-implemented property **definition** in a `class` or `struct`.

This:

```
interface IFoo
{
    String Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Means: "`IFoo` has a **public**<sub>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#detailed-design)</sub> `String` property named `Bar` which has a getter and a setter."

This:

```
class Foo
{
    String Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Means: "`Foo` has a **private**<sub>[2]</sub> `String` property named `Bar` which has a getter and a setter, and the getter and setter are both auto-generated by the compiler and operate on a hidden instance field.

---

Note that the syntax used in the interface is unrelated to the syntax used by implementation in the `class` or `struct`. So given the same `IFoo` as above...

```
interface IFoo
{
    String Bar { get; set; }
}
```

...we can have:

```
// Using auto-implemented property:
class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public String Bar { get; set; }
}
```

```
// Using explicit backing field:
class Foo3 : IFoo
{
    private String bar;

    public String Bar
    {
        get { return this.bar; }
        set { this.bar = value; }
    }
}
```

```
// Using expression-body syntax with a backing field:
class Foo4 : IFoo
{
    private String bar;

    public String Bar
    {
        get => this.bar;
        set => this.bar = value;
    }
}
```

```
// Using explicit interface implementation with a backing field:
class Foo5 : IFoo
{
    private String bar;

    String IFoo.Bar
    {
        get { return this.bar; }
        set { this.bar = value; }
    }
}
```

---

```
// You can also use explicit interface implementation with an auto-implemented property:
class Foo6 : IFoo
{
    String IFoo.Bar { get; set; }
}
```

```
// However, if it's a getter-only property you won't be able to set a property value in the constructor - but you can initialize it inline:
interface IReadOnlyFoo
{
    String Bar { get; }
}

class Foo7 : IReadOnlyFoo
{
    String IReadOnlyFoo.Bar { get; } = "foo"; // ok
}

class Foo8 : IReadOnlyFoo
{
    public Foo8()
    {
        this.Bar = "foo"; // <-- Error. `Bar` is not a member of `this`.
        // You also can't cast `(IReadOnlyFoo)this` because `IReadOnlyFoo` does not contain a setter.
    }

    String IReadOnlyFoo.Bar { get; }
}
```

---

> Is the private field in interfaces not generated the same as in classes

Interfaces don't have fields, **interfaces only have virtual methods** (or rather: an `interface` can be thought-of as a single vtable). Note that internally: properties and events are also fundamentally virtual methods (also note that while internally they're virtual calls, implemented interface methods are not automatically `virtual` (in the C# sense) in that a subclass of an interface implementation cannot arbitrarily `override` any interface member<sub>[3]</sub>.

Also not to be confused with "Default interface implementations" in C# 8.0 which a more akin to extension methods than treating interfaces as classes, because interfaces still cannot have fields.

You should also familarise yourself with C#'s expression-bodied member syntax:

```
class Foo2
{
    String bar; // this is a private instance field

    String Bar // this is a private instance property
    {
        get => this.bar;
        set => this.bar = value;
    }
}
```

---

Since C# 8.0, certain explicit modifiers on `interface` types are now permitted: for example, the `public` and `virtual` (or `sealed`) modifiers are now allowed on interface members. You can only use the `private` and/or `sealed` modifiers on DIM members, which means the `Bar` declarations below are all equivalent:

```
interface IFoo
{
    String Bar { get; set; }

    abstract String Bar { get; set; }
    
    public String Bar { get; set; }

    public abstract String Bar { get; set; }
}
```

...but none of these `Bar` properties result in a `String` field existing. [As per the C# 8.0 specification on DIM members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#detailed-design) (emphasis mine):

> **Interfaces may not contain instance state**. While static fields are now permitted, instance fields are not permitted in interfaces. **Instance auto-properties are not supported in interfaces**, as they would implicitly declare a hidden field.

While `public` and `abstract` are allowed on interface property declaration, you cannot use `private` or `virtual` *unless* that property has fully-defined `get` (and/or `set`) accessor body because the `private` and/or `virtual` modifiers indicate the property uses DIM methods (which means if you want a DIM property to store or load data those bodies will need to reference other properties or methods in the same `interface`), like the `OuterProperty` definitions below, which are all equivalent and result in identical IL+metadata output:

```
interface IFooWrapper
{
    IFoo Underlying { get; set; } // Implicitly `public abstract` btw

    public String OuterProperty
    {
        get { return this.Underlying.Bar; }
        set { this.Underlying.Bar = value; }
    }

    public String OuterProperty
    {
        get { return this.Underlying.Bar; }
        set { this.Underlying.Bar = value; }
    }

    public virtual String OuterProperty
    {
        get { return this.Underlying.Bar; }
        set { this.Underlying.Bar = value; }
    }
}
```

---

[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#detailed-design) Disregarding Explicit Interface Implementation, of course.
[2] Class members are private by default if they don't have an explicit access-modifier.
[3] Subclasses can reimplement an interface which will have the effect of overriding any virtual-calls to that interface member, but *only* if the member is accessed through an interface reference rather than through an object reference to the class's supertype.

Comment: Did `String Bar { get; set; }` syntax inside interface exist before C# 3.0, before it existed as auto-implemented property syntax for classes?

Comment: @miran80 The `String Bar { get; set; }` syntax existed since C# 1.0 as it's used for interface properties, however it was not supported for class properties (as auto-implemented properties) until C# 3.0 and was extended again in C# 4.0.

Comment: @dai, you mentioned that the properties aren't auto implemented, they are just declarations, could you please help me understand  when would this be considered not a declaration but an implemented one. From Microsoft documentation - [link] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties - In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors.

Comment: they also mention that - You can't declare auto-implemented properties in interfaces.Auto-implemented properties declare a private instance backing field, and interfaces may not declare instance fields. Declaring a property in an interface without defining a body declares a property with accessors that must be implemented by each type that implements that interface.
Is declaring a property without body not auto implemented property, if it is then why Microsoft says that Auto Implemented Can't be declared in interfaces because that's what auto implemented property is ,a property without body.

Comment: @RajeevVerma The "auto-implementation" of properties is an implementation detail - and interfaces (by definition) are not concerned with implementation details. I think you misunderstand what interfaces are.